# Validating a webhook signature AND using the body in NextJS

Tags: next.js, webhooks, signing

I'm trying to both validate and use the body response in a [Lemonqueezy](https://docs.lemonsqueezy.com/api/webhooks#signing-requests) webhook request in NextJS

I'm getting the signature validation to work, but the body object is then empty(presumably consumed by the signature validation).

I tried cloning the request, but this doesn't seem to do anything.

How do I get to validate the signature AND use the request body in NextJS?

Here's my code

```
// Next.js API route support: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import crypto from "crypto";
import getRawBody from "raw-body";
import clone from "clone-deep";
import { json } from "micro";

export const config = { api: { bodyParser: false } };

type Data = { message: string };

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<Data>
) {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    const clonedReq = clone(req);

    const rawBody = await getRawBody(clonedReq);
    const hmac = crypto.createHmac(
      "sha256",
      process.env.LEMONSQUEEZY_SIGNING_SECRET
    );

    const digest = Buffer.from(hmac.update(rawBody).digest("hex"), "utf8");
    const signature = Buffer.from(
      req.headers["x-signature"].toString() || "",
      "utf8"
    );

    const valid = crypto.timingSafeEqual(digest, signature);

    console.log("valid", valid);
    if (valid) {
      const body = await json(req);
      console.log("body", body);
      res.status(200).json({ message: "Success" });
    } else {
      res.status(500).json({ message: "Illegal method" });
    }
  } else {
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Illegal method" });
  }
}
```